# How to use a view function on all pages in Django?

Tags: django, view, django-views

I'm building an app in Django in which I have a layout where I have the navbar and I extend this layout to each page.

In order to have the navbar to receive the proper variables from the view I have to write the same code on each view. There has to be a way to write this code once and affect directly the layout so I won't need to type it multiple times but I haven't found the answer.

How can I write the function one time? Something like a global variable in Django I guess.

I hope I managed to explain myself ok, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you create context_processors.py somewher in your app.
then you write the function needed, something like:

```
from .models imoprt Somemodel

def alltimefunc(request):
     something = Somemodel.objects.all()
     return something
```

finally you add it in the settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            'your_app_name.context_processors.alltimefunc',  #here
        ],
    },
   },
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here comes [context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/api/) handy in these kind of situations. You can write a function and register it with template engine in settings.py file.  This way you can write code once and it will affect directly to the layout.